# Help solving a coupled differential equations system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this system:

$$(1)   \frac{dx_1}{dt} = -4x_2$$

$$(2) \frac{dx_2}{dt} = 4x_1$$

What I do is:

$$x_1 = \frac{1}{4}\frac{dx_2}{dt} \rightarrow \frac{dx_1}{dt} = \frac{1}{4}\frac{d^2x_2}{dt^2}$$

Substituting in (1):

$$\frac{1}{4}\frac{d^2x_2}{dt^2} = -4x_2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{4}\frac{d^2x_2}{dt} + 4x_2 = 0$$

The roots of the characteristic equation are $\pm j4$ (here j is square root of minus 1).

So, the solution I get for the above equation is $x_2 = A_1e^{4jt} + A_2e^{-4jt}$. [WolframAlpha seems to agree with this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2F4%29*x%27%27%28t%29%20%2B%204*x%28t%29%20%3D%200%2C%20x%280%29%20%3D%200)

The problem I'm trying to solve also states that $x_2(0) = 0$. Substituting in the above equation, I get that $A_1 = -A_2$

However, I know for a fact (I have the solution in my book) that this is wrong, $A_1$ must be equal to $A_2$.

If, instead of doing the above, I solve this:
$$\frac{-1}{4}\frac{d^2x_1}{dt} - 4x_1 = 0$$

Which comes from:

$$(1) \frac{dx_1}{dt} = -4x_2 \rightarrow x_2 = -\frac{1}{4}\frac{dx_1}{dt} \rightarrow \frac{dx_2}{dt} = -\frac{1}{4}\frac{d^2x_1}{dt}$$

And substituting in (2):

$$-\frac{1}{4}\frac{d^2x_1}{dt} = 4x_1$$

Then I reach the same solution as above, for $x_2$, but for $x_1$. My initial conditions state that $x_1(0) = 2$, so in this case I do get $A_1 = A_2$.

What am I doing wrong in my first solution?

Comment: I don't see an error. No reason to believe a book, they are written by busy people and mistakes happen

Comment: You have two different differential equations. One in terms of $x_1$ and another in terms of $x_2$. As far as I can tell you made no error in solving for $x_2$, where you rightly conclude that $A_1 = -A_2$ if $x_2(0) = 0$. The coefficients $A_1, A_2$ however, will be different in the solution for $x_1$ where the initial condition is different. The coefficients of the solutions of the two differential equations are not the same.

Comment: @Paul bear in mind that I did reach the same solution as the book in the second attempt, so I believe that solution is correct.

Comment: @prcssngnr sorry, I don't understand. Are you suggesting that both solutions are correct? So, depending on in which terms I solve the system, I can get different coefficients?

Comment: Both differential equations are the same, but the initial conditions are different and therefore the coefficients of the solutions are different. And actually, indeed $A_1 = -A_2$ in the solution to the equation for $x_2$ since $x_2(0) = 0$, but $A_1 + A_2 = 2$ and so $A_1 = 2 - A_2$ in the solution for $x_1$ since $x_1(0) = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the differential equations:

$$ \frac{1}{4}\frac{dx_1^2}{dt^2} + 4 x_1 = 0 $$
$$ \frac{1}{4}\frac{dx_2^2}{dt^2} + 4 x_2 = 0 $$

you derived are the same, apart from initial conditions, and the solutions are:

$$ x_1 = A_1 e^{4ti} + A_2 e^{-4ti} $$
$$ x_2 = B_1 e^{4ti} + B_2 e^{-4ti} $$

as you noted. We have that $x_1(0) = 0$ and $x_2(0) = 2$ and so:
$$ 0 = A_1 + A_2 \implies A_1 = -A_2 $$
$$ 2 = B_1 + B_2 \implies B_1 = 2 - B_2 $$

Therefore the solution you obtained for $x_1$ is correct. The solution for $x_2$, however has different coefficients.

Comment: In the OP, it was stated that $x_1(0)=2$ and $x_2(0)=0$. They were just mentioned in reverse order. As a last step, insert that $\dot x_1=-4x_2$ to reduce the number of free parameters further, hopefully to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Until you get more comfortable with linear systems with a constant coefficient matrix, your way is likely more intuitive for you and thus more reliable.

Another very short way to get to the solution, just for comparison purposes, is to consider the complex-valued function $$z=x_1+ix_2.$$ Then $z(0)=2+0i$ and $$\dot z=4iz,$$ so that from the general solution of the exponential DE one gets
$$
z(t)=z(0)e^{4it}=2\cos(4t)+2i\sin(4t).
$$